# How to display message box error/success after save button clicked

Tags: vb.net, listbox, save, messagebox

I have been searching the web for the solution but for some reason cannot seem to find it.

I want to display a message box, either saying "Saved Successfully" or an error message, when the "save" button is clicked.

Here is the code for the button so far:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveKeywords.Click

    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\TESTING")
    Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\TESTING\Keywords.txt")
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        w.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
    Next
    w.Close()


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Step 1: implement a way to detect a problem - add a Try Catch; Step 2: dispose of your StreamWriter; Step 3: Display error message set in the catch, or the default "Saved Successfully"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Try Catch to detect errors in your program, so it if errors then it will send a error message. Eg:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveKeywords.Click

Try 

IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\TESTING")
Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\TESTING\Keywords.txt")
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    w.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
Next

MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully")

Catch ex as exception

Messagebox.show("Error when saving. " & ex.tostring, "Data error ")

Finally
w.Close()

End Try

End Sub
```

The finally will always close the streamwriter stream even if succeeds saving or errors.

On another note i would personally write to the file this way,

```
Dim FileLocation as string = "C:\TESTING\Keywords.txt"

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileLocation, ListBox1.ToArray, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

(Above line is untested so ListBox1.ToArray might not work, but easily fixed if doesn't)

Comment: As you suspected, ListBox1.ToArray will not compile. However, `ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String).ToArray` will create a string array from the items in the ListBox. `WriteAllLines` is happy with `IEnumerable(Of String)`, so for your purpose, you could use `ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the button click should contain as little code as possible and call a sub or function that contains most of the code the code like below, but that's not the question.

You should as much as possible check for errors in the code - In your case checking that the directory already exists.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveKeywords.Click
    SaveFile("C:\TESTING\Keywords.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub SaveFile(fileName As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path.GetDirectoryName(fileName))
    End If
    Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter()
    Dim i As Integer
    Try
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving File: " & fileName & vbCrLf & "Exception Details" & vbCrLf & ex)
    Finally
        w.Close()
End Sub
```